# Is there a way in Sql Server to find what columns in a view are not indexed

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

I'm looking at some incredibly complex views in a Sql Database. I've found several columns that are in the join or where clause that are not indexed. Needless to say, this is a performance hit.

Is there a way, preferably in SSMS, to have it tell me any column that is not indexed that should be.

This is Azure Sql Database, not Sql Server.

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know you just need to enable "Automatic Tuning" on Azure SQL Database? It will create all missing indexes for you and will automatically verify that performance of queries has improved. It will also drop unnecessary indexes and force the optimizer to use the best query plan. All this is just one click away. Learn how to enable it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automatic-tuning).

This is the benefit for developers of using PaaS database services.